# How can I change Culture after push on a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, resources

I like to change the language used in buttons, labels etc.. when you choose a language from a button (or something else, but for now just push a button).
But the only thing that changed is the Label with the selectedLanguage, but I also want the Content of the other Label changed in the right Language. What do I have to do to refresh the view that it shows the right Language (Culture)?

My XAML code snap:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="{x:Static res:Strings.ProjectName}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Label Content="{Binding SelectedLanguage}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Button Name="btnNL" Content="{x:Static res:Strings.BtnPushMe}"  Command="{Binding PushMe, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="NL" Width="100" Height="45" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Name="btnEN" Content="{x:Static res:Strings.BtnPushMe}" Command="{Binding PushMe, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="EN" Width="100" Height="45" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>

    </Grid>
```

My ViewModel has the following code:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand m_pushMeCommand;
    private SynchronizationContext syncCtx;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        syncCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        if (Language == null)
        {
            Language = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }
        Language.Clear();
        Language.Add("NL");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Language { get; set; }

    public string SelectedLanguage
    {
        get { return Language[0].ToString(); }
    }

    public ICommand PushMe
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_pushMeCommand == null)
            {
                m_pushMeCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    (g) => ChangeLanguage(g)
                );
            }

            SendPropertyChanged("ChangeLanguage");

            return m_pushMeCommand;
        }
    }


    private void ChangeLanguage(object param)
    {
        var language = param as string;
        CultureInfo culture = null;

        if (Language == null)
        {
            Language = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        Language.Clear();

        switch (language)
        {
            case "NL":
                Language.Add("NL");
                culture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
                break;
            case "EN":
                Language.Add("ENG");
                culture = new CultureInfo("en-EN");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (culture != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        }

        SendPropertyChanged("SelectedLanguage");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a simple line of code that does something like this:

```
private void refreshContent(string content)
{
    foreach(custom_control.button button in grid) //add gridname
    {
        button.content = content;
    }
}
```

Now I understand you're looking for a more subtle approach but I think this will do nicely, unless you have more then 50 buttons on screen.

EDIT: Take a look at mm8's answer aswell.

Comment: Yes I have a lot and also a lot of label text (static).

Answer (score 1):

The XAML processor will set the `Content` of the `Label` and the `Buttons` to the static values that you have defined in the markup and then these values won't ever change.

If you want to be able to dynamically change the culture and have the UI elements update accordingly during runtime, you should read the following CodeProject article:

**WPF Localization Using RESX Files:** https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files

It uses a custom markup extension called `Resx` to get the job done:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Resx ResxName=MyApp.TestWindow, Key=MyText}"/>
```

The built-in `Binding` class has no support for automatically detecting a culture change I am afraid so you will need a custom solution.